# Extract specific rows from spreadsheet using a key with R

Tags: r

I have a spreadsheet Y that has thousands of rows

I would like to extract a few hundred specific rows identified by key X

I used intersect function to generate object Z as below, but do not know how to proceed.

Many thanks

```
Z<-intersect(X$PatientID, Y$Patient.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%in%`:
Sample Data

```
Y <- data.frame(PatientID = LETTERS,
                Var1 = 1:26)

key <- data.frame(PatientID = c("A", "W", "V"),
                  Var1 = c(1, 22:23))
```

Using `%in%`:

```
want <- Y[Y$PatientID %in% key$PatientID, ]
```

Output:

```
#    PatientID Var1
# 1          A    1
# 22         V   22
# 23         W   23
```

Note if you needed to use `intersect`, you would just do this:

```
Z <- intersect(Y$PatientID, key$PatientID)

want <- Y[Y$PatientID %in% Z,]
```

And it would give you the same output

Answer (score 0):

You can merge:

base R

```
merge(Y,unique(X[,"PatientID",drop=F]))
```

dplyr:

```
dplyr::inner_join(Y, dplyr::distinct(X,PatientID))
```